# How do I get all classes of an object / instance via code

Tags: python, instances

As an example for what I mean, the official Blender API [says](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.modifiers) that the "modifiers" property of Objects has two classes:

**bpy.types.ObjectModifiers** and **bpy.types.bpy_prop_collection**

Additionally, bpy.types.ObjectModifiers has **bpy.types.bpy_struct** as its base class, which means the "modifiers" property has three classes in total.

My Question is: What code snippet can I use to find ***all*** the classes a specific object/instance has?

I found several different commands to get a class of an instance, but none of those manage to get *all* classes, which is what my actual goal is.
Simply using multiple of those command lines probably isn't guaranteed to work with every instance.

For reference, these are some of the commands I found while researching, together with their outputs:

```
>>> mods = bpy.data.objects['Cube'].modifiers


#what I'm searching for:
>>> somefunction(mods)
(<class 'bpy.types.ObjectModifiers'>, <class 'bpy_prop_collection'>, <class 'bpy_struct'>)


#what I have:
>>> type(mods)
<class 'bpy_prop_collection'>
>>> mods.__class__
<class 'bpy_prop_collection'>
>>> mods.rna_type
bpy.data.objects['Cube']...Struct
>>> mods.rna_type.identifier
'ObjectModifiers'
>>> mods.rna_type.bl_rna
<bpy_struct, Struct("ObjectModifiers") at 0x00007FF6C55D5080>
>>> mods.bl_rna
<bpy_struct, Struct("ObjectModifiers") at 0x00007FF6C55D5080>
```

Also, even if I figured out that it has *bpy.types.ObjectModifiers* as one of its classes, I cannot get `__mro__` to show me the *bpy.types.bpy_prop_collection* class, only *bpy.types.bpy_struct*:

```
>>> bpy.types.ObjectModifiers.__mro__
(<class 'bpy.types.ObjectModifiers'>, <class 'bpy_struct'>, <class 'object'>)
```

The classes don't actually need to be callable, their names would be enough.

Comment: AFAIK you can't access it https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3h4g.png

Comment: but `type(mods)` does give me `<class 'bpy_prop_collection'>`
I don't want to call the classes somehow, I just want to find out their names

Comment: You can get their names via rna: https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-rebuild-the-add-modifier-menu-layout/ (Can't find the Q&A right now, pretty sure there is a good one).